# How to store individual words from an Excel cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of phrases and would like to write a macro that can store the data in a jagged array such that each individual array would contain all the words in a particular cell stored as strings.

For example if column A could contained the following phrases:

```
foo bar foo    
hello world    
test 123
```

I would like to create the following jagged array:

```
{{"foo", "bar", "foo"}, {"hello", "world"}, {"test", "123" }}
```

I am not too familiar with VBA. How can I declare a jagged array? and what would be the best method for extracting the individual words and storing them in that array?

Comment: `split` looping the array from `range().value`

Answer (score 1):

Use Array around some Splits.

```
dim arr as variant
arr = array(split(.range("a1"), chr(32)), split(.range("a2"), chr(32)), split(.range("a3"), chr(32)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code would be like this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR(), vResult()
    Dim vSplit, i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim myArray As String
    vDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        vSplit = Split(Trim(vDB(i, 1)))
        'ReDim vR(0)
        For j = 0 To UBound(vSplit)
            ReDim Preserve vR(j)
            vR(j) = Chr(34) & vSplit(j) & Chr(34)
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To i)
        vResult(i) = "{" & Join(vR, ",") & "}"
    Next i
    myArray = "{" & Join(vResult, ",") & "}"
    Range("b1") = myArray
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is easy when you have just 3 or 4 cells in a column which is populated but if you have say 10 cells or more then it will become difficult. Use `collection of collections` instead

```
'~~> API to Create a GUID, a unique 128-bit integer used for 
'~~> CLSIDs and interface identifiers.
'~~> We will use it create unique key for our collection
Private Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (pGUID As Any) As Long

Public Sub Sample()
    Dim JagCol As New Collection, item As Collection
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lRow As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tmpAr As Variant, itm As Variant, subItm As Variant

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Find Last Row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Loop through the cells in Col A
        For i = 1 To lRow
            Set item = New Collection

            tmpAr = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value)

            '~~> Create a sub collection
            For j = LBound(tmpAr) To UBound(tmpAr)
                item.Add tmpAr(j), CreateGUID
            Next j

            '~~> Add sub collection to  major collection
            JagCol.Add item
        Next i
    End With

    For Each itm In JagCol
        For Each subItm In itm
            Debug.Print subItm
        Next
        Debug.Print "-----"
    Next
End Sub

'~~> Function to create unique key
Public Function CreateGUID() As String
    Dim i As Long, b(0 To 15) As Byte
    If CoCreateGuid(b(0)) = 0 Then
        For i = 0 To 15
            CreateGUID = CreateGUID & Right$("00" & Hex$(b(i)), 2)
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

**Screenshot**
[image]